# To call python code implemented as a class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to python, just installed vs code on my Ubuntu 18.04 and ran some simple python code such as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)  # Create a list of evenly-spaced numbers over the range
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))       # Plot the sine of each x point
plt.show()                   # Display the plot
```

but how could I call a python snippet defining a class?

Here I got a solution for the "longest palindromic substring" problem, implemented as a class, but without any entry point similar to C++ 's `main()` function. How shall I call this "longest palindromic substring" code?

```
class LPS:
    """
    @param s: input string
    @return: the longest palindromic substring
    """
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        if not s:
            return ""

        n = len(s)
        is_palindrome = [[False] * n for _ in range(n)]

        for i in range(n):
            is_palindrome[i][i] = True
        for i in range(1, n):
            is_palindrome[i][i - 1] = True

        longest, start, end = 1, 0, 0
        for length in range(1, n):
            for i in range(n - length):
                j = i + length
                is_palindrome[i][j] = s[i] == s[j] and is_palindrome[i + 1][j - 1]
                if is_palindrome[i][j] and length + 1 > longest:
                    longest = length + 1
                    start, end = i, j

        return s[start:end + 1]
```

Comment: `LPS().longestPalindrome(s)`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh shall I run this in a Terminal (i'm on ubuntu) or, inside vs code run "Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal" command to create a terminal inside vs code then run `LPS().longestPalindrome(s)`?

Comment: you can add this line below your python script, and the code will be executed, sorry I am not very familiar with VSCode

Comment: It doesn't need to be an instance method, since it uses no instance (or class) data associated with `self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of class (and after it!) call

```
LPS().longestPalindrome("someString")
```

Note the parenthesis after `LPS` and before `.longestPalindrome`. This way you create an object of class `LPS` allowing you to call its "nonstatic" methods (see that `longestPalindrome` has `self` as a parameter).

Another way would be to call it as

```
lps = LPS()
lps.longestPalindrome("someString")
```

Alternatively, omit the `self` parameter which is completely redundant in your case and call as

```
LPS.longestPalindrome("someString")
```

*Note:* `self` is like `this` in Java.

*Edit:* I see some answers omitting `()` after `LPS`, like `LPS.longestPalindrome(“someString”)`. This is highly unhigienic Python, just like using `””` for character literals and `’ ’` for strings, although both are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in Java or C we create the object of the class and access any method of that class via the object.

But in Python you can simply use the class name followed by the dot operator and finally the method you want to access, like

> **LPS.longestPalindrome(s)**

in your case

Answer (score 2):

You can simply import your class by name and use class method in another python script or same script like this

```
import LPS 
LPS.longestPalindrome(0, "Your String")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by adding these lines of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Creates object of your class
    lp = LPS()   
    # Calls the longesetPalindrome() with "prateek" as argument
    response=lp.longestPalindrome("prateek")
    # Prints the response which the function returns.
    print(response)
```

Since, you are new to python and if you are looking for something similar like 'main()' of c++ in python then you can use

**if __name__ == "__main__":**

it works almost similar to main() but it is not a function.
Basically, Every Python module has its **name** defined and if this is ‘**main**’, it implies that the module is being run standalone by the user and we can do corresponding appropriate actions.
The  **if __name__ == “main”:** is used to execute some code only if the file was run directly, and not imported.